# weird c++ string bug with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, compilation

Can someone explain what is happening here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string kek = "kek";
    cout << "test" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, every time I compile with g++, and I declare a `string` variable, I can't see any output, no compile or runtime errors, simply no output.

[image: way too weird]

Now, if I change the code to be this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // string kek = "kek";
    cout << "test" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

then everything works.

Does anyone know what the problem is here?

I am currently on Windows 10, using gcc 8.1.0.

Edit:
same thing but using bash, linux compile
[image]

i think the version of mingw i had is bugged so trying to reinstall it

Comment: The code looks fine to me.  You are just going to have to debug it to see what is really happening at runtime.

Comment: `g++ main2.cpp -o out.exe` shouldn't you run `out.exe` instead of `out`?

Comment: @Ch3steR both are equally acceptable in windows.

Comment: that's not the issue here, in linux g++ it works fine btw

Comment: Probably wrong file name, wrong path, or something along the lines of these.

Comment: @WaisKamal nah that clearly not the issue, as when i commnet the string declaration,
and recompile it is printing the next line.

Comment: @WaisKamal Got you. I have not worked with windows I did not know that.

Comment: Could also be your antivirus disabling your program because it believed your unsigned executable could be a threat or a dll conflict caused by having more than 1 version of the mingw runtime dlls in your path.

Comment: @drescherjm maybe that's actually what happened as removing minGW 32bit, seemed, to fix it for me, ( and installing 64bit ).

Comment: @RemyLebeau i see, iam just didn't really use debug tools other then prints up untill this point, so i guess when for some reason it just didn't print anymore i got lost.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so still i have no idea what that bug was about,
but when i had it, the version of MinGW i had was 32bit,
changing the MinGW installation to 64bit, fixed that issue.

i have changed nothing, except removing MinGW 32bit from my comp,
and setting the MinGW 64bit.

```
Swaping from MinGW 32bit to 64bit, fixed the issue.
```